# Efficient way to power stacked rows of pistons?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

How can I power two vertically stacked rows of pistons, hopefully with a minimal number of repeaters?  I can get the bottom row powered with just a line of redstone on the gold blocks behind as shown, but can't figure out how to do something similar for the top row at the same time.

[image: stacked rows of pistons]

Comment: Use inverted torches placed behind the bottom row with blocks on top

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually save on the redstone torches and just raise your "golden block with redstone" line by one block.

The result is this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care about inverting the signal beforehand, simply use redstone torches behind the upper pistons to power everything:

[image: The build]

Comment: This works due to piston quasi-connectivity, where a piston is powered by powering the block above it. Inverting the signal with torches is not needed at all, a line of blocks with redstone dust on top next to the top piston row is sufficient.